# Locale-specific XFontSet expansion

Tags: c, fonts, localization, x11, motif

In my Motif application (source code is [here](https://gist.github.com/unix-junkie/9666928acab34bff186264a0a130998a), requires Motif **2.1**+ (`-lXm -lXt -lX11`) and a C99-compliant compiler; on *Cygwin* should be additionally linked with `-liconv`), I'm trying to get an [`XFontSet`](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R7.7/doc/man/man3/XCreateFontSet.3.xhtml) instance converted from an encoding-agnostic *XLFD* (like `-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--*-90-*-*-p-0-*-*`) to be correctly expanded into multiple individual `XFontStruct` entries (`...-iso8859-1`, `...-iso8859-5`, `...-iso10646-1`, etc.) matching the current locale.

I've found that in some locales (`en_US.UTF-8`, `ru_RU.ISO-8859-5`), `XFontSet` expansion works perfectly while in others (`ru_RU.UTF-8`, `ru_RU`) it does not (inappropriate individual fonts in a fontset), resulting in characters other than those from the `Latin-1` plane rendered incorrectly.

Questions:

1. How can I rule out either Motif or X11 client libraries (`libXt`, `libX11`) as the main suspects?
2. Particularly, (how) can I display a text label using a font set (`XFontSet`) rather than a regular font (`XFontStruct`) without relying on Motif -- ideally with the Athena widget set?
3. Speaking of plain `libX11` API, is my understanding correct I should experiment with [XmbDrawString() and XwcDrawString()](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XmbDrawString.3.html) family of functions?

If you have additional comments reg. the code, which don't directly answer the above questions but can help track down the problem -- those are welcome.

---

## The TL;DR version

I'm particularly interested in getting Cyrillic displayed properly regardless of the current locale, provided that:

- the locale is supported by X11, and
- Cyrillic is representable in the locale's charset.

This leaves me with the following list of locales:

- `ru_RU`;
- `ru_RU.ISO-8859-5` (which should be the same as ru_RU, but it's not, see below);
- `ru_RU.KOI8-R`;
- `ru_RU.CP1251`;
- `ru_RU.UTF-8`;
- `en_US.UTF-8` as well as any `xx_YY.UTF-8`.

`ru_RU`, with no loss of generality, can be easily replaced with `uk_UA`, `be_BY` or `bg_BG`.

In my test code, I'm creating `XmLabel` instances with labels produced by different `XmStringCreate*()`/`XmStringGenerate()` factory methods.

Motif **2.3.4** has generally shown to be Cyrillic-capable, with a few exceptions (or regressions with regards to Motif **2.1**). I'm not sure whether the regressions stem from Motif itself (`libXm`) or X11 client libraries (`libXt`, `libX11`). X11 font path was the same in all tests, so a particular X server or X font server is not to be blamed.

Basically, I've found 2 issues when using Motif **2.3.4**:

### `ru_RU` locale support

**Reference rendering** obtained in `ru_RU.ISO-8859-5` locale:

[image: Reference rendering obtained in ru_RU.ISO-8859-5 locale]

As you can see, the full Russian alphabet is displayed correctly, regardless of `XmString` factory used.

In each of the three cases, the application prints the contents of the `XFontSet` instance to stdout:

```
locale: ru_RU.ISO-8859-5
run-time charset: ISO-8859-5
XmStringCreateLocalized():
    XmFONT_IS_FONTSET (ru_RU.ISO-8859-5): -monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--*-90-*-*-p-0-*-*, -monotype-arial-regular-r-normal--*-90-*-*-p-0-*-*
        -monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-5
        -monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-5
XmStringCreate():
    XmFONT_IS_FONTSET (ru_RU.ISO-8859-5): -monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--*-90-*-*-p-0-*-*, -monotype-arial-regular-r-normal--*-90-*-*-p-0-*-*
        -monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-5
        -monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-5
XmStringGenerate(XmCHARSET_TEXT):
    XmFONT_IS_FONTSET (ru_RU.ISO-8859-5): -monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--*-90-*-*-p-0-*-*, -monotype-arial-regular-r-normal--*-90-*-*-p-0-*-*
        -monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-5
        -monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-5
```

---

Now, the same application launched in `ru_RU` locale. Motif **2.2**:

[image]

For some reason, `XFontSet` only contains the `KOI8-R` font instead of the `ISO-8859-5` font:

```
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-koi8-r
```

Motif **2.3**:

[image]

In this case, nothing is rendered, while `XFontSet` contains more fonts than is actually necessary:

```
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-1
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-koi8-r
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-microsoft-cp1251
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-5
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso10646-1
```

This is a regression compared to Motif **2.1.0** (versions **2.1.30** and later are affected).

### `ru_RU.UTF-8` locale support

**Reference rendering** obtained in `en_US.UTF-8` locale:

[image]

In addition to the 3 `XmString` factories tested in 8-bit mode, [`XmStringGenerate(XmMULTIBYTE_TEXT)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xmstringparsetext) is additionally tested. `XFontSet` contains the following entries (actually, all possible `XFontStruct` entries for the Monotype Arial font):

```
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-1
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-2
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-3
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-4
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-5
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-koi8-r
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-7
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-9
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-13
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-15
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso10646-1
```

---

Now, the same in `ru_RU.UTF-8` locale:

[image]

Looks like an incorrect `XFontStruct` is used, despite `XFontSet` instance contains all the necessary `XFontStruct` entries:

```
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-1
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-koi8-r
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-microsoft-cp1251
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso8859-5
-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--12-90-100-100-p-0-iso10646-1
```

**Update**: it turns out in `ru_RU.UTF-8` locale, the `LANG` environment variable is to be blamed (with the empty `LANG` or `LANG=C` or `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, Cyrillic is displayed correctly), while `LC_ALL` can be safely set to `ru_RU.UTF-8`.

This is a regression compared to Motif **2.2** (versions **2.3.0** and later are affected).